# If one checkbox within a div that contains multiple checkboxes is checked, add class to all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to all checkboxes within a div if just one checkbox within that div is checked. I don't think that I'm too far away, but I'm stuck. Here's what I've got.

```
var checkboxes = $("#myContent input[type='checkbox']");
$(document).on("click", checkboxes, function() {
    if(checkboxes.is(":checked")) {
        checkboxes.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
    else {
        checkboxes.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
});
```

I've tried putting an alert in place of the addClass/removeClass, but I get the same alert both when checking a box and unchecking (the alert that I had in the "else" statement). I must be close here, does anyone know what I'm missing?

My HTML is as follows (I'm also using Smarty):

```
<div class="pd5" id="myContent">
                        {foreach from=$cLibrary key=k item=l}
                        <div class="clrBoth {cycle values=',AltRows0'} pd5 fLeft p100">
                            <input type="hidden" name="isform[{$k}]" value="{$l.isform}" class="valid" />
                            <div class="fLeft px20">
                                <input type="checkbox" value="{$k}" name="contentValue[{$k}]" id="contentData_{$k}" class="invalid" {foreach item=cn key=po from=$selectedContent}{if $cn eq $k} checked {/if}{/foreach} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var checkboxes = $("myContent input[type='checkbox']");
checkboxes.on("click", function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        checkboxes.removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To check the conditions use `if(this.checked)`
2. If you define the checkbox selector in a variable, the dynamic elements won't count. So there is no use of delegating the events.

---

```
$(document).on("click", "#myContent :checkbox", function (e) {

    if (this.checked) {
        $('#myContent :checkbox').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#myContent :checkbox').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nEuqE/1/)**

Comment: My apologies - typo when adding my question! I do actually have the # as it's an id.

Comment: And unfortunately, no luck with this.checked either

Answer (score 0):

i found this work

```
 $(function(){

  $(".checkbox").on("click",function(){

    if($(this).is(":checked")){

      $(".checkbox").removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");

    }else{

      $(".checkbox").removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }

  })
});


  <div id="wrapper">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</div>
```